# How do I connect multiple broker in mosquitto MQTT iOS?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mqtt

I am using mosquito MQTT. I can connect to a single broker from my code and subscribe/publish for the same. I need to achieve a multiple broker connection from the code dynamically. How do I do that?

Comment: I never came across such situation, but how about this, you create as many as objects of classes from MQTTClient or whatsoever to connect to the different brokers.

Comment: @Fennec i agree with your comment. But i need to multiple number of broker connections. I can't create multiple instance for MQTTClient. If i supposed to do that last broker only connected, rest of the broker connections were disconnected.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by connecting to multiple brokers? Brokers can bridge to each other to share topics if needed.

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for your comment. if i use multiple object i will use multiple receivers?